# Appending (via rename?) `.bad` to files identified by `tests/test_.*`

Tags: linux, regex, rename

### What do I want?

Given the following directory structure:

```
.
├── bar.py
├── hap
│   ├── bla.py
│   └── tests
│       └── test_hap.py
└── hip
    ├── testimony.py
    └── tests
        ├── foo.py
        └── test_hip.py
```

I'd like to go to the following:

```
.
├── bar.py
├── hap
│   ├── bla.py
│   └── tests
│       └── test_hap.py.bad
└── hip
    ├── testimony.py
    └── tests
        ├── foo.py
        └── test_hip.py.bad
```

So, I want to append `.bad` to all files starting with `test_` which are located in a `tests` directory.

### What have I tried?

From the tips given in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15012631/rename-files-and-directories-recursively-under-ubuntu-bash), I tried the following:

```
shopt -s globstar
rename "s/tests\/test_.*/tests\/test_.*\.bad/" **
```

But the `.*` in the `new` part of the substitution pattern `s/old/new` seems to be auto-escaped. How can I let the second `.*` be interpreted as a regular expression?

Furthermore, using `test_.*\.bad$` gives me the following:

```
Final $ should be \$ or $name at (eval 1) line 1, within string
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find is great for things like this (note this may only work if your paths have no spaces).

```
find /directory/path -type f -name "test_*" -exec mv {} {}.bad \;
```

Find can filter on the directory tree to find what you want, then the exec argument to find allows you to substitute whatever was found into "{}".

Comment: For my use case I really needed to specify to only search in dirs called `tests` as specified. so Instead of `-name "test_*"` I used `-path "*tests/test_*`.